# Content duplicating in loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason the tweets in the else statement below are duplicating and I can't figure out why.

If tweets include the phrase, they receive the redacted div. If tweets do not include the phrase, they should have regular text. However, if the tweets do not include the phrase, those tweets are appearing twice for some reason.

Does this have to do with the way the loop is set up?

```
<section id="tweets">
 <ul>
<% tweet = @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
@<%= tweet.user.screen_name %>
<%= image_tag(tweet.user.profile_image_url) %>

    <% current_user.blockedshows.each do |blockedshow| %>
        <% blockedshow.phrases.each do |phrase| %> </br>
            <% if tweet.text.include?(phrase.text)%>
                <li><%= link_to check_if_redacted(tweet.text), "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" %></li>
            <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to tweet.text, "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" %></li>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loops are executing once for each redacted phrase within each `blockedshow`, which will duplicate the tweet output for every phrase. Try using `any?` to check the tweet against all of the phrases at once, and emit the correct `<div>` based on that result:

```
<% if current_user.blockedshows.flat_map(&:phrases).flatten.any? { |phrase| tweet.text.include? phrase.text } %>
  <!-- Tweet contains at least one blocked phrase. -->
  <li><%= link_to check_if_redacted(tweet.text), "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" %></li>
<% else %>
  <!-- Tweet contains no blocked phrases. -->
  <li><%= link_to tweet.text, "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" %></li>
<% end %>
```

That test is getting a bit messy, so this is a good candidate for functionality to refactor into a helper method. In the helper for this view:

```
def is_redacted? tweet
  @phrases ||= current_user.blockedshows.map(&:phrases).flatten.map(&:text)
  @phrases.any? { |phrase| tweet.text.include? phrase }
end
```

And then change the `if` in the view:

```
<% if is_redacted? tweet %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I inputted your code and unfortunately it is still duplicating, now for tweets with blocked phrases and tweets without blocked phrases.

Comment: Really? Only one branch of the `<% if %>` should be followed for each  `tweet`. Are there duplicates in the `@tweets` collection, maybe?

Comment: Ahh nevermind. Forgot to take out my previous blockedshows block when testing the new if statements. It works now. Thanks so much! Really was struggling to figure that one out.